# InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension seq2seq Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting this error in `seq2seq.sequence_loss` even though first dim of logits and labels has same dimension, i.e. batchSize

I have created a seq2seq model in TF 1.0 version. My loss function is as follows :

```
    logits  = self.decoder_logits_train
    targets = self.decoder_train_targets
    self.loss     = seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits=logits, targets=targets, weights=self.loss_weights)
    self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(self.loss)
```

I am getting following error on running my network while training :

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1280,150000] and labels shape [1536]
     [[Node: sequence_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](sequence_loss/Reshape, sequence_loss/Reshape_1)]]
```

I confirm the shapes of `logits` and `targets` tensors as follows :

```
a,b = sess.run([model.decoder_logits_train, model.decoder_train_targets], feed_dict)
print(np.shape(a)) # (128, 10, 150000) which is (BatchSize, MaxSeqSize, Vocabsize)
print(np.shape(b)) # (128, 12) which is (BatchSize, Max length of seq including padding)
```

**So, since the first dimension of `targets` and `logits` are same then why I am getting this error ?**

Interestingly, in error u can observe that the dimension of logits is mentioned as `(1280, 150000)`, which is `(128 * 10, 150000)` `[product of first two dimension, vocab_size]`, and same for targets i.e. `(1536)`, which is `(128*12)`, again product of first two dimension ?

**Note : Tensorflow 1.0 CPU version**

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be a bit misleading, as you actually need first and second dimensions to be the same. This is written [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss):

> logits: A Tensor of shape [batch_size, sequence_length,
>   num_decoder_symbols] and dtype float. The logits correspond to the
>   prediction across all classes at each timestep.
>
> targets: A Tensor of shape [batch_size, sequence_length] and dtype
>   int. The target represents the true class at each timestep.

This also makes sense, as `logits` are probability vectors, while `targets` represent the real output, so they need to be of the same length.

Comment: My logits and targets are of same shape but getting error from the loss function. My logits are of shape (128,10,150000) , but error msg mentions the shape as (1280,150000), i.e. it flattens the first and second dimension and thus the error arises.

Comment: Didn't you write that the targets are of shape (128, 12) ?

Comment: Yeah targets are of shape (128,12) as they are having padding also .
Link to code : https://github.com/adakum/seq2seq/blob/philly_compatible/seq2seq_model.py

Comment: Based on the documentation, you cannot have different second dimension in logits and targets. They both need to be equal to sequence_length. In your case one of them is 10 and the other is 12.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the issue coz of which this error I am getting. My decoder inputs is of dimension(128,12)  but the decoder_rnn is only unrolling 10 times. :/ Do u hv any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your way of padding wrong. if you padded _EOS to the end of target seq, then the max_length(real length of target sentence) should add 1 to be [batch, max_len+1]. Since you padded _GO and _EOS, your target sentence length should add 2, which makes it equals 12.

I read some other people's implementation of NMT, they only padded _EOS for target sentence, while _GO for input of decoder. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you and I understood the problem:

**The problem:**

You run the decoder using this parameters:

- `targets` are the decoder_inputs. They have length `max_length` because of padding. Shape: `[batch_size, max_length]`
- `sequence_length` are the non-padded-lengths of all the targets of your current batch. Shape: `[batch_size]`

Your logits, that are the output `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode` has shape:

`[batch_size, longer_sequence_in_this_batch, n_classes]`

Where `longer_sequence_in_this_batch` is equal to `tf.reduce_max(sequence_length)`

So, you have a problem when computing the loss because you try to use both:

- Your logits with 1st dimension shape `longer_sequence_in_this_batch`
- Your targets with 1st dimension shape `max_length`

Note that `longer_sequence_in_this_batch` <= `max_length`

**How to fix it:**

You can simply apply some padding to your logits.

```py
logits  = self.decoder_logits_train
targets = self.decoder_train_targets

paddings = [[0, 0], [0, max_length-tf.shape(logits)[1]], [0, 0]]
padded_logits = tf.pad(logits, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=0)


self.loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits=padded_logits, targets=targets, 
                                  weights=self.loss_weights)
```

Using this method,you ensure that your logits will be padded as the targets and will have dimension `[batch_size, max_length, n_classes]`

For more information about the pad function, visit 
[Tensorflow's documentation](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/pad)